# PreparedStatements should throw Exception instead of warning

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am using PreparedStatements to write to database and sometimes I see following in my logs:

```
 2015-02-02 15:44:14,601  WARN SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: 22007
 2015-02-02 15:44:14,602  WARN Incorrect datetime value: '2011' for column 'time_end' at row 1
```

However this is completely useless as I cannot see where in the code the problem is. Is it possible to force Connection/PreparedStatements to throw exceptions instead of these warnings?

Comment: @Vojtech [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er) might help you

Comment: This does not help as I need to find a stacktrace to see where this error is happening. This is Java issue.

Comment: Do you get an SQLException? Can you send the code snippet of the prepared statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much help, but you can retrieve the warnings by a call to `Connection.getWarnings()` or `PreparedStatement.getWarnings()` or `ResultSet.getWarnings()` and examine the warning object there. These methods all return an `SQLWarning` object, which is the first in a chain; call `warning.getNextWarning()` to see subsequent messages.

This, of course, means you'll have to alter all your DB code to track down the problems; sorry I don't have a better option right now. If there is a way to force the JDBC code to throw these as real catchable exceptions, it is probably driver-specific.

Comment: Just one last thing: when you call ps.executeUpdate, it does not return ResultSet, but int. When you call preparedStatement.getResultSet(). Is it equivalent then to call connection.getWarnings?

Comment: In that case, you can call `preparedStatement.getWarnings()`, yes? Play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint at the line: "handler.prepare( warning )" in SqlExceptionHelper class, and then at the debugger (At least Intelli Idea does) have a stacktrace on the left side (on tab Frames), which you can navigate until you reach the class that executed the query, and work from there.

You also have all debugging variables, etc.